# How can I keep pond water "alive"?

Tags: microbiology, microscopy

I've been preparing wet slides for my kids to look at from pond water. I have a mason jar of pond water. What can I do to keep the microbes in the jar alive going forward so that we can look at it any time we want without having to go back to get more pond water.

I remember we did something like this in 7th grade biology, it seems like we put in sugar, or oatmeal, or something. I can't quite remember that though, it's been over 30 years. Thanks!

---

Thanks for the comments. The pond water I get keeps for a couple of days easily. I can always get more at the pond.

If I want amoebas, I go near dark and get them at the bottom of the pond. If I just want paramecia and other critters, I grab some scum and fill the rest of the jar up with water.

The paramecia water I give moderate sunlight. The amoeba sample I keep in the dark. And I just pitch it after a few days. No Legionella for my family, please and thank you.

Comment: How long do you want to keep it. I think the water will have a sustainable microecosystem if it is kept open.

Comment: Is there anything in particular in the pond water you want to look at specifically? Do you want to look at microbes, or more tardigrades and daphnia, etc? You could always fix the slides. Sunshine should keep it going on a microscale, but stuff like brine shrimp or around that size require snacks.

Comment: I'd like to keep it alive indefinitely. As far as tardigrades/daphnia/microbes, yes, yes, and yes!

Comment: And how open would it need to be? I have the mason lid sealed on it, but with a bunch of holes in the lid.

Comment: You want to keep live water indefinitely? I don't know if you'll be able to tell if it gets colonized by Legionella.

Comment: Yikes. Maybe I'll just go back to the well then. Or the pond, in this case.

Comment: The answer will be to replicate the conditions as best possible, given the biotic and abiotic variables it could be very difficult to answer this.

Comment: "No Legionella for my family, please and thank you.".

Comment: "No Legionella for my family, please and thank you.". Legionella pneumophila ocurs in oxygen rich, fresh, standing water, maintained at temperatures between 30 and 50°C (86 - 122°F). Infection occurs trough the air, by inhaling water droplets from aerosols (drinking Legionella containing water is harmless). Unlikely to become infected by a jar of pond water, I would say... There's nothing wrong with being cautious, but there's no need to exaggerate...